# Search Column In Excel For Content From Another Cell, And Return Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've seen a lot of questions that almost solve my problem ... but not.

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns:

- The old URLs of a website (ex - https://example.com/xyz/
- The story slug (ex - /xyz/)
- The new URL with the permalinks changed (ex - https://example.com/category/xyz/)

I'm trying to create a formula that will match up the old and new URLs using the slug.

Basically, column A has the old URL, B the slug, C is empty, and D has the new URLs but in the wrong order.

I want to have C2 search the full column of D for the partial match of the slug (which will be unique) and if it finds it, put the value of the cell that matches from D into C2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&C2&"*",D:D,1,FALSE)
```

Comment: If we were on Reddit I'd pass you some Gold. :D

Comment: Please click the check mark beside the answer.  It will add points.